# Django @receiver decorator update ForeignKey object when object is edited

Tags: django, django-models, decorator, python-decorators, receiver

I have 2 classes which are standalone. The Trade model calculates many statistics based on the Entry model objects that relate to the Trade object. These stats only get calculated when the trade object is saved.

Therefore when updating an Entry object manually due to an import process amendments. I also need that Entry object to send a signal to the related (ForeignKey) Trade object to be saved. Otherwise, a user would need to find that Trade object and click save. This would be massively inefficient.

Here's my current setup and error message.
Is this the right way to approach this issue or are their problems with this approach/better alternatives?

models.py

```
class Trade(models.Model):
    ...
    @receiver(post_save, sender='portfolios.Entry')
    def update_trade_object(sender, **kwargs):
        trade = Trade.objects.get(pk=kwargs['instance'])
        trade.save()

class Entry(models.Model):
    ...
    trade = models.ForeignKey(Trade, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
```

Current Error:

```
TypeError: Field 'id' expected a number but got <Entry: Entry object (605)>.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, kwargs['instance'] is the Entry instance that is saved. If you want to get the trade instance related to this entry instance, you can basically do:

```
kwargs['instance'].trade
```

The approach you have here is fine, you detect when an Entry is saved, and do some calculations about it. Another approach could be overriding the **save** method of Entry model, but your approach is fine and thats what I do in such situations as well.

But I do not understand why you save the trade instance when the entry is saved. Do you do some specific calculations on Trade save method, or have another signal receiver for Trade to do the calculations you mentioned? Instead of emulating trade save method when a related entry is saved, you can call the method to do the calculations you mentioned directly on the signal receiver method for Entry save, but that of course depends on how your code is organized.

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks! I do get pyCharm underline message "unresolved attribute reference 'trae' for class 'str'" but that seems to be fine. Also yes I have a custom def save(self): a function that saves many other functions that calculate statistics based on new entries associated to this trade object if that makes sense. What you suggested would work as well but the calculated stats are then saved to fields. I call them my #automated fields, and the user does not edit these they are just calculated and saved for faster future retrieval.

Answer (score 0):

Pk is waiting for number not the whole object .

I think it should be: instance.pk or instance.id .

```
 @receiver(post_save, sender='portfolios.Entry')
 def update_trade_object(sender,instance, **kwargs):
    trade = Trade.objects.get(pk=instance.pk)
    trade.save()
```

Comment: Thanks for the attempt ahmend! You're def right that I was calling the wrong thing but I needed the foreign key of the field trade and I believe like @Ozgur hinted at your answer would just be calling the Entry pk.